# Injecting values from nested hash into string

Tags: json, ruby

I am trying to inject variables into a JSON string. I figure there is an easy way to do this, but I have not found it yet. Here is the basic goal. I have a JSON string that I want to inject variables into. I have a multidimensional hash that I want to pull arrays from.

JSON:

```
{"room":"814","token":"myfaketoken","message":"The test passed with status %{result.status} from test %{test}"
```

Hash:

```
hash = {:result => {:success => true, :status => 'healthy'}, :test => example}
newString = json % hash
```

This works great for non-nested things, but I haven't found a great simple alternative for nested things.

Comment: do you have control over the json string? there is no built-in way to inject nested hash values into a string. the easiest answer will depend on whether you're required to use json someone else is giving you or whether you have control over the way the json can look.

Comment: I can change the json to my liking

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with a json the first step would be to convirt the json to a hash and then work with it as a hash, and once done convert it back to json. You can easily do this with the [json module](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html).

Example:

first require the json module at the top of the file:

```
require 'json'
```

...

```
hash_from_json = {"room":"814","token":"myfaketoken","message":"The test passed with status %{result.status} from test %{test}"}
=> {:room=>"814", :token=>"myfaketoken", :message=>"The test passed with status %{result.status} from test %{test}"}
```

Now do what you want to do with the hash. I.e. something like:

```
hash_from_json[:message] = "The test passed with status %{result.status} from test %{test}"
```

then convert it back to json

```
formatted_json = hash_from_json.to_json
 => "{\"room\":\"814\",\"token\":\"myfaketoken\",\"message\":\"The test passed with status %{result.status} from test %{test}\"}"
```

Comment: This issue here though is extracting the `%{result.status}`. You can't use a period in that. as far as I know, you can only use single dimension hashes

Comment: @Miverson I think that if the result is standardized then you might consider using a regex pattern to match the portions of the string that you want to extract and then replace them. Specifically you're going to want to use [named captures](https://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html#method-i-named_captures) I can recommend http://www.rubular.com/ as a good ruby regex tool.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think string format [`%`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/String.html#method-i-25) can work with nested hashes.

You could use [`gsub`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/String.html#method-i-gsub) with a block to manually parse the string, though. The block converts `%{result.status}` to `[:result, :status]` and uses this array with [`Hash#dig`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Hash.html#method-i-dig) (Ruby 2.3+ is required) :

```
message = 'The test passed with status %{result.status} from test %{test}'
hash = { result: { success: true, status: 'healthy' }, test: 'example' }

new_message = message.gsub(/%\{(.*?)\}/) do
  hash.dig(*Regexp.last_match(1).split('.').map(&:to_sym)) 
end

p new_message
#=> "The test passed with status healthy from test example"
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to flatten your nested hash:

```
def flatten hash, del='_', prefix=''
  new = {}
  hash.each do |k, v|
    if v.respond_to? :keys 
      new.merge! flatten(v, del, "#{prefix}#{k}#{del}")
    else
      new["#{prefix}#{k}".to_sym] = v
    end
  end
  return new
end
```

Using it would look like this:

```
> h = {one: "blah", two: {three: "foo", bar: "gah"}}
 => {:one=>"blah", :two=>{:three=>"foo", :bar=>"gah"}} 
> flatten h
 => {:one=>"blah", :two_three=>"foo", :two_bar=>"gah"} 
> flatten h, '.'
 => {:one=>"blah", :"two.three"=>"foo", :"two.bar"=>"gah"}
```

This will be more costly than the gsub/regex answer, but it should work on old versions of ruby.